# Is there a way to click an element using Partial text or complete Text using Appium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to click an element with text "No, Thanks" using below code, I tried various options so far such as

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(text(),'THANKS')]").click();

 driver.findElement(By.name("No,THANKS")).click();
 driver.findElementByName("No,THANKS").click();
```

There is no other element with same text. I am using Appium Driver and Samsung device.

Comment: Could show me your website?

Comment: Have you tried to inspect your element with the Appium inspector? Based on my experience, text on iOS mobile elements might be available from `name` or `label` attributes.
And it is better to use iOSNsPredicate strategy instead of xpath. It works way faster!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is TextView, you can consider the following

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='No, Thanks']")`

Answer (score 1):

Seems you were close. The text *No, Thanks* contains a **`,`** character in between which you need to avoid. So effectively you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath* 1:

  ```
  driver.findElementByXPath("//*[starts-with(., 'No') and contains(., 'Thanks')]").click();
  ```
- *xpath* 2:

  ```
  driver.findElementByXPath("//*[contains(., 'No') and contains(., 'Thanks')]").click();
  ```

Comment: How can I use contains for Cart? //XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="Cart, 1"]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'No, Thanks')")).click();
```